# Any C++ example for DRCSIM v2.5?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just could find examples for python at DRCSIM v2.5 and my old C++ ROS node is not working anymore as we should disable BDI control and use AtlasCommands and not JointCommands anymore... There is any workaround for this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2564/any-c++-example-for-drcsim-v2.5?/) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's a [new tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.6/controller_synchronization) for the forthcoming drcsim 2.6 that's in C++.  That should mostly work for you on 2.5, with the exception of the `desired_controller_period_ms` variable in the command message; that's not present in 2.5.

You can also look at [the code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/e5a3e7fe5ddacea2dcdf74fb55d336961bdf6ad1/ros/atlas_msgs/pub_atlas_command.cpp?at=drcsim_2.5) for the `pub_atlas_command` tool, which we use for testing.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-05-07**:
That helped. Thanks